# "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ "

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

```
_dbEntities.EmployeeAttendances.Where(x => x.DailyDate.Date.Equals(DateTime.Now.Date)).ToList();
```

> "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported."

How can i do this get employees data on based on current date in linq query?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`EntityFramework` cannot convert `DateTime.Date` to SQL. So, it fails to generate expected SQL. Instead of that you can use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime()` or `DbFunctions.TruncateTime()`(based on `EF` version) method  if you want to get `Date` part only:

```
 _dbEntities.EmployeeAttendances
            .Where(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DailyDate) == DateTime.Now.Date)
            .ToList();
```

***Additional info:***

`EntityFunctions` methods are called ***canonical functions***. And these are a set of functions, which are supported by all Entity Framework providers. These canonical functions will be translated to the corresponding data source functionality for the provider. Canonical functions are the preferred way to access functionality outside the core language, because they keep the queries  portable.

You can find all canonical functions [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738626(v=vs.110).aspx) and all Date and Time Canonical Functions [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563(v=vs.110).aspx).

***Update:***

As of EF6 `EntityFunctions` has been deprecated for `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions`.

Comment: thanks it works well you tell me how to get year from a date in this query dailydate contains date and time

Comment: EntityFunctions doesnt contain Year i have tried before

Comment: @Mike I have updated my answer again. It seems that, they removed this method fro some reason.

Comment: As of .NET 4.6.2 (maybe earlier, I didn't check) EntityFunctions has been depreciated for System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions

Answer (score 9):

Dont use EntityFunctions in EF 6. TruncateTime is in the DbFunctions class:

```
DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DailyDate)
```

Answer (score 7):

If the `DailyDate` property is already just a date, instead of a date and time, then it would be simplest to just use:

```
// Outside the query so it becomes a constant, effectively
var today = DateTime.Today;
var employees = _dbEntities.EmployeeAttendances
                           .Where(x => x.DailyDate == today)
                           .ToList();
```

If it *does* have times (making the above fail), you could always use:

```
// Outside the query so it becomes a constant, effectively
var today = DateTime.Today;
var tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);
var employees = _dbEntities.EmployeeAttendances
                           .Where(x => x.DailyDate >= today &&
                                       x.DailyDate < tomorrow)
                           .ToList();
```

... or use `TruncateTime` as Farhad's answer suggests. I'd still recommend evaluating `DateTime.Today` first though:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var employees = _dbEntities.EmployeeAttendances
                       .Where(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DailyDate) == today)
                       .ToList();
```

Note that `Today` (like `DateTime.Now`) uses the system default time zone. You should think carefully about whether that's what you want.

Comment: thanks Jon for your reply can you tell me how to get year from a date in this query dailydate contains date and time

Comment: @Mike: It's unclear why just the year is relevant - you said you wanted it based on the date, not just the current year.

Comment: yeh thats ok its another problem i am facing

Comment: @Mike: So you should ask it in an separate question.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case it helps someone...
In EF 6, EntityFunctions is obsolete, use [DbFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) class instead.
You might want to include the Namespace `System.Data.Entity;`

eg:

```
_dbEntities.EmployeeAttendances.Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DailyDate) == DateTime.Now.Date).ToList();
```