# EF: How to compare today date for filter the data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using Entity Framework with MYSQL database. I am trying to get result from following query.

```
select COUNT(*) from tbldata where CreatedBy is not null and created is not null and DATE(Created) = DATE(NOW())
```

Above query returned accurate result. I have tried this query in E.F but it returns zero Count.

```
var todayDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

_db.TblData.Where(c => c.CreatedBy != null && c.Created != null && c.Created == todayDate)
                .Count();
```

How can I compare only date value in E.F?

Thank you

Comment: `c.Created.Date == DateTime.Now.Date` is `Created` of type `DateTime`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this one too "c.Created.Value.Date == todayDate". it throws exception "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities"

Comment: Then try this: `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.Created) == DateTime.Now.Date`

Comment: Please note: Since EF6 `EntityFunctions` is obsolete and is replaced with `DbFunctions`

Comment: I am using latest version of EF. this time thorws exception "FUNCTION dbname.TruncateTime does not exist"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28381268/the-specified-type-member-date-is-not-supported-in-linq/30803487#30803487

Answer (score 0):

try to use like this, extension methods not work for linq.

```
   _db.TblData.Count(c => c.CreatedBy != null && c.Created != null && c.Created.Date == DateTime.Today);
```

Comment: "Created" Column already DateTime Type.

Comment: If that is the case than it must have time value in it, and if it has time value that you cannot compare it with date value as it will always be false.

Comment: I have updated my answer please can you verify it now.

Comment: did that work for you?